# How do I connect two modems (RJ45) into a single computer?

Tags: networking, router, modem

I have two modems here with each of them connecting to a computer through RJ45. However I have a single computer, is there a way to connect those two modems to a single computer? I've looked into ethernet hub, network switch, routers but I'm not really sure which one to use (They seem to connect a set of computers or a set of computers into one modem). I also have seen USB-to-Eternet adapters but I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that 2 modems will solve? Simplest solution install a secondary network card into the computer.

Comment: It completely depends on what you're trying to do, which you don't say.

Comment: I wanted to combine their speed, I've already [found a software](http://lifehacker.com/5976620/connectify-dispatch-merges-your-available-internet-connections-into-one-fat-super-fast-pipe) but don't know how to do the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do you can either just connect two network cards into your computer, or if you want to team your internet connections, you need to use something like a peplink router http://www.peplink.com/